# Should EF attributes be on the class or interface when doing Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When defining a c# class with entity framework attributes, should these be placed on the interface or the class?

example:

```
public interface IUser 
{
        [Column("user_id")]
        int Id { get; set; }

}

public class User : IUser
{
        [Column("user_id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure I follow.  Are you talking about setting up code first migrations, extending the generated partial classes or something else entirely?

Comment: Define "should". Do you mean _"On which one should they be in order to be recognized by Entity Framework"_, or "should" as in "best practice" or _"Please enumerate all ways of annotating models because I couldn't find the documentation"_?

Comment: @CodeCaster Which is the best-practice?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey This is for EF with code-first.

Comment: Consider using fluent API.